# Missing BigInteger features under F# Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, f#

I understand that certain .NET features are not available under Silverlight, but I've noticed that BigInteger under F# Silverlight has less features than [advertised on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). For example, MSDN says the [explicit BigInteger to UInt16 method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268211%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and several others should be available, yet F# only shows op_Explicit overloads for alias' `int32`, `int64`, and `float`.

What am I missing here? Could this have something to do with F#'s .NET 2.0 compatible big integer implementation? Note that I am using Silverlight 4.0 with corresponding Silverlight 4.0 F# assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

The FSharp.Core Silverlight 4.0 build contains its own System.Numerics.BigInteger implementation, similar to how the F# for .NET 2.0 build does. But there is a System.Numerics assembly available as part of the standard Silverlight 4.0 libraries (referenced in the MSDN docs) so I am not sure why F# need include its own. I think this is a "bug" and will file a report.